# Experience with submitting HTML/JS apps (e.g., jQuery Mobile & PhoneGap) to Apple AppStore

Tags: javascript, app-store, cordova, jquery-mobile

What's your experience with submitting HTML/JS applications, e.g., jQuery Mobile & PhoneGap to the Apple AppStore?

- How to achieve compliance with the Apple UI guidelines?
- Performance: PhoneGap seems to aditionally slow down the app?

Answer (score 5):

We did submit jQuery/Phonegap app to Appstore. Apple block us - we still don't understand why. 
We submit same app to Google play (price 5$) - 17 downloads for 12 days WITHOUT any ads or promotion.

---

We found the user interface of your app is not of sufficient quality to be appropriate for the App Store. Apps that provide a poor user experience are not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Specifically, we noticed your app:

- has deep and confusing navigation
- did not integrate with app content and/or iOS features

We believe it is always best for you to determine what features are best for your users. However, please keep in mind Apple and Apple customers place a high value - and have high standards - for the user interface and the experience an app provides. Apps should be engaging and exciting, enabling users to do something they couldn't do before; or to do something in a way they couldn't do before or better than they could do it before. Focusing on a primary problem to solve or need to fulfill, apps should include a feature set that intuitively and comprehensively addresses those needs and exceeds users' expectations. And apps should be specific to the iOS platform to take the fullest advantage of the iOS in delivering a robust user experience.

Please evaluate whether you can make the necessary revisions to improve the user experience of your app. 
If you cannot - or choose not to - revise your app to be in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines, you may wish to build an HTML5 web app instead. You can distribute web apps directly on your web site; the App Store does not accept or distribute web apps.

HTML5 is the major new version of HTML and enables audio and video to play natively in the browser without requiring proprietary plug-ins. Using HTML5, web apps can look and behave like native iPhone and iPad apps, and using HTML5's Offline Application Cache, a web app can work even when the device is offline. With web apps, you have flexibility to deliver as much or as little functionality as you desire.

To get started with iPhone or iPad web apps, please review Getting Started with iPhone Web Apps.

For a description of the HTML elements and attributes you can use in Safari on iPhone, check out Safari HTML Reference: Introduction.

---

We dont understand how
-two level deep list can be "has deep and confusing navigation"
-why our app "did not integrate with app content and/or iOS features"

Again before submitting we make beta-testing with users - 12 person from 12 tell us that app navigation and data presentation clean and easy.

But probably not for Apple genius-stuff.

Hope next few years we will forget about Apple.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm working on a PhoneGap-based application myself, I haven't gotten to the point of submitting it to the App Store.

You might consider posting your question over at the [PhoneGap Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap), as several folks there have successfully gone through the submission process.

Answer (score 0):

Use Phonegap minified in your index.html reference.  The state of jQuery Mobile is Alpha 4 right now; there are some performance issues that are really troubling me, but they look to be going beta soon and I am sure they will address them.  I highly expect Apple to be supportive of an HTML5-produced application and I would expect you are far from the first to do this.  One thing that does concern me is that Apple has yet to find way to distribute HTML5-based apps except through shells such as this.

Answer (score 0):

I work for AppMobi, which has a competing product...but the end result is very similar.

We've had a bunch of people submit iOS apps (including us) with no issues.  The only time problems arise is due to content or application specific problems, not with how it was built.

As to jquery mobile (along with jqtouch and others), the uiWebView lags behind Safari with updates and performance, so it may run fine with Safari but slower in the container.  That's one problem everyone deals with.  I'd encourage you to look at http://zeptojs instead, since it's smaller and aimed at mobile devices, with an attempt of being jquery compatible.  I'm always testing javascript frameworks and have not found a cross platform UI based one that's performed acceptable.

*plug* And I'd encourage you to check out http://xdk.appmobi.com if you are just doing html/js/css based apps.